Return date and time AND format cell's background with onEdit
I work in logistics and I'm trying to create a sheet so my guys can input Tracking ID with a barcode/QR scanner and have it do the following:

Record date and time of the first time a value is entered into a cell onto an adjacent cell (example: input into B1, C1 gets date & time, then if B1 gets another value, C1 is unchanged. Input into any other column, unless specified, is ignored. Repeat for F-G and J-K).

Keep cell white/uncolored if it's empty or contains certain character (example: white if it's untouched/contains "VN", red if it has value but no "VN").

Apply to same columns, regardless of current sheet (getActiveSheet?).


Sorry for not being specific enough, I'm not a coder and just trying to automate some menial tasks with Gsheet. I'm thinking of onEdit(), but no idea if it can format and fill at the same time while lightening up the sheet.
Tried =ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(B4:B10003="","",C4:C10003<>"",C4:C10003,1*1,Now()))
but it needs references, which slows the sheet down massively. Oh and conditional formatting, lovely tools.

Hi! Can you share a minimal reproducible sample for your data set and expected result for the community to have better oversight about your Goal on your project? Can you also clarify this part Keep cell white/uncolored if it's empty or contains certain character (example: white if it's untouched/contains "VN", red if it has value but no "VN"). which cells includes this?

On your point number 1, I also want to understand how you planning to implement the unless stated are you looking for some sort of a check box?

Using onEdit(e) and SetValue a Timestamp:
I understand that you have 3 requirements for your goal. I understand that you are new to Stackoverflow. I tried to cover things that are clear on your post.
1.Record date and time of the first time a value is entered into a cell onto an adjacent cell (example: input into B1, C1 gets date & time, then if B1 gets another value, C1 is unchanged. Input into any other column, unless specified, is ignored. Repeat for F-G and J-K).

Apply to same columns, regardless of current sheet (getActiveSheet?).

You are on the right path on this one this can be achieved by utilizing onEdit(). I created a solution on Apps Script for you to cover these two.
Sample Code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  var tsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(editRow,editColumn+1);
  var tsValue = tsRange.getValue()
  if(editColumn == 2 || editColumn == 6 || editColumn == 10){
    if(tsValue == ""){
   var date = new Date();
    tsRange.setValue(date);}
 }
}

Sample Output:

Note:

If you have minimal experience with Apps Script. Please read this
article to learn more how to implement this on your Sheet.

Your 2nd Bullet point really falls far from the 1st Question I would
suggest posting it as another question along with an additional of
information about which cells were you referring to, cells that
colors will change and also what is the cells that you need to refer
to make the changes.

With lack of specificity with the unless specified I suggest that deleting the date stamp works better with your current work flow this way it will still be fast, if you have other specified action on your mind please feel free to comment.

Please make sure that the cells are pre formatted to your desired format using the built in format button the Google Sheets.


References:
onEdit
Event Objects
